# How install several "like buttons" on the same page of a website?

Tags: video, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, share

My website shows my work as a film director and there are several videos on each page.
I want to give to visitors the opportunity to like, comment and share the videos. The share plugin make this possible easily but it will disappear and the "like button" will replace it.
But because meta tags are necessary for the like button i don't find the solution to install several like buttons on the same page for several vides. I hope I'm clear enough ! Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying a href for the individual like button that points to a dedicated page for each item on the list?

Comment: Thank you for answering Morten. I thought about your solution that seems to be the only one. This solution makes it possible only for me to share my videos on Fbk page but visitors of my website won't be able to see and use like buttons because they will navigate on the non-dedicated pages. It's a shame cause it could have been a good source of traffic. So it's impossible to put multiple like buttons on one page ? I don't understand why the share plugin will disappear.

Comment: No problem.. I don't use facebook in any way, so I am not much of an expert on this subject, but I might as well try to help out..

Comment: I also meant to add this: you could always just build your own like button. All you really need is to send off a request to fetch some URL, yes?